# Mobile App detection from browser

Tags: javascript, detection, mobile-application

I want to detect via JS if a user does or does not have a particular app installed.

I know about the app store tag that will pop the generic "download this app" if they don't have it installed. I'm not asking about that.

I have a concept, but it's incomplete. This would try to target both iPhone and Android devices.

Knowing that a link with a particular prefix can trigger an app to open:

1. Target a hidden iframe with JS to open a url prefixed to trigger that app
2. That page would fire a post message back to the parent if it loads, indicating the app was not opened.
3. If the app exists, the message would never be fired back to the parent, since it would open in the app.

Unfortunately, my client does not want app to open (or attempt to open) automatically, but simply know wether or not it's installed.

Thoughts? Blaring errors in my logic? Work-arounds? Existing solutions?

Thanks

Comment: What system are you targeting? Android, iOS?

Comment: As someone who was recently researching this very effort, I'm sad to say you might be headed for a dead end. The closest we've come is to launch the app, or go to the appstore upon launch failure. (For Android, Intent links will help achieve a better user experience - but not specifically what you're asking for)

Comment: Maybe the NSA has a database you could query? Overall, I think we ought to be happy that we're not exposing our entire app selection to every website we visit. Now, if your client has control over the app they're checking for, it might be possible for the webpage to open the app invisibly and then tell the app to pass a message back to the browser behind the scenes.

Comment: On iOS 6, you can use [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's likely no way to do this, because generally speaking you aren't allowed to poke around on a user's device from a web page. Even though what apps a user does or doesn't have installed isn't the most sensitive of personal information, it would still be a bit of a security/privacy concern to expose that information to scripts coming from the web. The app store tag is probably the closest you're going to get, since it's an official API to provide similar but protected functionality.

Comment: Useful information. Generally, this is better posted as a comment, though - since it's not a solution to the OP's problem (not to say that any solution even exists)

Comment: Isn't it a valid answer though to say that something doesn't exist and give the reasoning for it? I'm not asking for more information, I'm just stating the likely resolution to his question. Apologies though it this is poor form -- I'm new here and still trying to figure out the distinctions between when you should post where.

Comment: This is the way I've understood SO's question/answer policy though - For instance, if a question has incomplete information, it also likely needs a comment, and an answer should be impossible at that time. On the same token, if someone asks "How do I time travel" and the comment response is "Time travel is physically impossible", someone could revise their question to "Okay, I actually wanted to get user data from 5 minutes ago" - and someone could answer "Here's how to save data for later"

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to try to solve your problem, although none is especially good. Since iOS 6, you can use [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to promote an app.

The most obvious solution would be to hide any actions from the user, e.g. by preventing the activity from showing up after issuing the URL request. I don't have any experience with this and cannot tell you to what extent it might be possible to hide it.

To be honest, I have no idea whether the second approach will work on mobile devices. It has been used for desktop applications a lot and allows inter-application communication - including communication between the browser and the app. However, the possibilities might be limited due to the usually high security restrictions on mobile devices. This is a highly theoretical suggestion as I am pretty sure it is unsuitable, whether it is possible or not.
Your app must provide a tiny HTTP server on an unused but fixed port. Your JavaScript code can then use JSONP to communicate with the app (assuming the security restrictions of the browser don't prevent this). If communication fails, you may assume the app is not installed.

Before anyone attempts to criticize this approach, let me say that this is a theoretical possibility, might be unstable and is unsuitable for most apps. The efforts of running an HTTP server are far too high for such a secondary task.